# Dados duplicados

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma tabela onde os cliente criam o orçamento e a cada produto inserido um registo é feito pra separar, mais quero fazer um consulta pelo nome do cliente que o sistema não pegue mais de um, e sim um só. desde já Obrigado

Comment: Você pode ter vários com o mesmo nome, mas quer retornar só um? Ou seja o primeiro da lista? Você fez algum código até agora e poderia colocar junto? Ou a exemplificação de como estão as tabelas?

Comment: COnsegui já usando o DISTINCT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o `distinct`. Se você especificar melhor as suas condições e o banco utilizado ficaria mais fácil, mas seria algo assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cliente) FROM orcamento
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(nome) FROM `orcamento`; ja era ??

Comment: Não sei, como eu falei, sua pergunta foi vaga. Fale um pouco mais sobre o tipo de BD, as estrutura dos dados e sobre as condições desejadas que ficaria mais claro

Comment: @LukasAlmeidaII se a minha resposta foi útil, lembre-se de marcá-la como resposta. Obrigado.